# Chrome word replacement app json error

Tags: json

i am having a problem with my json code. I wanted to learn how to make an extension so I referred to a tutorial online, and I am not sure what is wrong with the json file. I will paste the code followed by the error below.

```
{"manifest_version": 2,
"name": "[Octopie]",
"description": "[Replaces all “Octopie” with Octopuses]",
"version": "1.0",
"content_scripts": [
    {
        "matches": [
            "*://*/*"
        ],
        "js": [
            "content.js"
        ],
        "run_at": "document_end"
    }
]}
```

The error comes up as:
[click on the link to view the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hWIBX.png)

Answer (score 0):

Your error message states that you have a syntax error, though the JSON you have provided here is valid, whcih can be confirmed on **[JSONLint](https://jsonlint.com/)**.

Your error message is complaining about a syntax error at the end of the third line, so assuming you have used the same JSON in both your application and your question, the most likely scenario is that your parser doesn't like your `“”` quotes. These should be replaced with single quotes:

```
{
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "name": "[Octopie]",
    "description": "[Replaces all 'Octopie' with Octopuses]",
    "version": "1.0",
    "content_scripts": [{
        "matches": [
            "*://*/*"
        ],
        "js": [
            "content.js"
        ],
        "run_at": "document_end"
    }]
}
```

Hope this helps!